# Multiple Prototype property with same name in Prototype Chain

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, prototype-chain

I know that object's(instance's) own property has higher priority than properties in instance's `.__proto__`. But what is the priority order when we have multiple properties with same name inside instance's `.__proto__`. Here's my code, I am trying to access `c`.

```
const Foo = function (fName,by) {
    this.fName = fName;
    this.by = by;
}
let a = {};
a.__proto__.c = "hello"
Foo.prototype.a = a;
let b = {};
b.__proto__.c = "bello"
Foo.prototype.b = b;
ins1 = new Foo("Mike",2000);
console.log(ins1.c);
```

This gives output as "bello". I am unable to find why this is happening and what is the rule by which Js decides this.

Comment: The code doesn't do what you might think it does. Just do `console.log({}.c)`, you'll find out this is something you should not do (because `a.__proto__ === b.__proto__ === any __proto__`).

Comment: @Teemu yes, that clears my doubt, thanks for clarification

Comment: When learning about the prototype chain, forget about `__proto__`. It's deprecated and should not be used. Make use of `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`.